# List of tokens available to trade via Ox API (Avalanche)

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to trade TEDDY on Avalanche via 0x, when I call the [tokens API](https://0x.org/docs/api#get-swapv1tokens) `curl -X 'GET' 'https://avalanche.api.0x.org/swap/v1/tokens' -H 'accept: application/json'` I only get AVAX, WAVAX, and WETH, are those the only supported Avalanche tokens at this time?

```
{"records":[{"symbol":"AVAX","address":"0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","name":"AVAX","decimals":18},{"symbol":"WAVAX","address":"0xb31f66aa3c1e785363f0875a1b74e27b85fd66c7","name":"WAVAX","decimals":18},{"symbol":"WETH","address":"0x49d5c2bdffac6ce2bfdb6640f4f80f226bc10bab","name":"Wrapped Ether","decimals":18}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the `/tokens` endpoint is not at all exhaustive, 0x API supports any ERC20 compliant tokens (without on-transfer fees).

Just pass the addresses of the tokens you want to trade as `sellToken` and `buyToken` parameters to the `/swap/v1/quote` request.

Here is an example request selling 1000 DAI for AVAX: https://avalanche.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=1000000000000000000000&sellToken=0xd586e7f844cea2f87f50152665bcbc2c279d8d70.

Please refer to https://0x.org/docs/api for more information.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks kimpers! For those finding this in the future you can find the token contract addresses on something like Nomics: https://nomics.com/assets/usdcavax-usd-coin-avalanche.